# Is there any way to enable & disable notifications in whole app using code?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

I have a task to create a switch button that will disable and enable notifications in my app.
How i'm supposed to do that? Is there any "MainNotification" Class?

Answer (score 1):

Save the value of the switch to shared preferences.  Then, whenever you create a notification, check the value of that preference.  To make it easier, I'd wrap the NotificationManager functions that create a notification in a helper function that checks the setting, and use that throughout the app rather than using the OS level ones directly.